# How to write JSON expression to get age value if age > 0

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I want get only age value if age is greater than 0 (age > 0). Please help the json path expression

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }
}
```

I have tried like this "$.[?($.age > 0)]" but not working

```
private void ageCondiionCheck(ReadContext context) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(customerJSON);
        Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL;
        ReadContext context = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(jsonString);
        String jsonPath = "$.[?($.age > 0)]"
        Object result = context.read(jsonPath);
        System.out.println("Age Value greater than zero : "+result.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: @Mr.P  Java language -- Object result = readContext.read(jsonPath);

Comment: pls paste your complete working code.. so we can advise on what you are doing wrong and how to achieve your desired output ...

Comment: @Mr.P Please see once code is posted

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your input JSON string is supposed to be a JSON array as follows: (I ignored some fileds)

```json
[
  {
    ...,
    "age": 26,
    ...
  },
  {
    ...,
    "age": 0,
    ...
  },
  {
    ...,
    "age": 18,
    ...
  }
]
```

**Code snippet**
It can be easily achieved by using `Jayway JsonPath`.

```java
System.out.println(JsonPath.parse(jsonStr).read("$[?(@.age > 0)].age").toString());
```

**Console output**

```
[26,18]
```

Answer (score -1):

one possible way (ES6)  ... consider you have an array of objects as below

```js
    var data = [
                {
                 "firstName": "John",
                 "lastName" : "doe",
                 "age"      : 26,
                 "address"  : {
                   "streetAddress": "naist street",
                   "city"         : "Nara",
                   "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
                 }
                },
                {
                 "firstName": "Jimmy",
                 "lastName" : "Bimbo",           
                 "age"      : 0,
                 "address"  : {
                   "streetAddress": "Lime street",
                   "city"         : "NYC",
                   "postalCode"   : "100-0002"
                 }
                }
               ]
    
    var filtered = data.filter(item => item.age > 0)
        
    console.log(filtered)
```